# Blazor: How to use a onclick event in MarkupString

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, markup

**The click-event is not working. I don't know why.**

In a foreach I create a String:

```
      html += $"<div style='padding: 5px;' @onclick='() => TerminClick({term.Sinr})'>";{date}</div>";
```

and put it into a MarkupString object:

```
      _terminContent = new MarkupString(html);
```

At the html I implement the content:

```
      @_terminContent
```

I got the method TerminClick(int id)

```
    public void TerminClick(int id)
    {
        logger.LogWarning($"Termin: {id}");
    }
```

At Chrome Dev Tools I check the code:
[image]

I tried also without parameter `{term.Sinr}` respectively `int id` and that also is not working. I set a breakpoint into `TerminClick()` it's never hit and also at the console `logger.LogWarning(..)` is never logged.

I tried also using `@onclick="@TerminClick(..)"`.

**How do I get the click event working using a MarkupString?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `StateHasChanged();` after create your divs.

For more information look this: [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: It does not help at my app. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it through using a loop at the razor file:

```
        @foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            <div style='padding: 5px;' @onclick="@(() => TerminClick(@term.Sinr))">@term.Date</div>
        }
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good for future reference to explain why this did not work. Blazor is not dynamic. Everything is predefined by means of compilation.

`MarkupString` only renders a string as HTML Markup. Nothing else will be attached here.

In your example, a proper way of adding elements to a parameter is to use a `RenderFragment` instead of a `string`, and appending to that `RenderFragment`.

Example component:

```
@myObject

@code {
    RenderFragment myObject { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int thisIndex = i;
            myObject += @<div>@thisIndex</div>;
        }
    }
}
```

The '@' character is important here, as this will be treated like any other Blazor element, and not as a string.

The best approach in this scenario is as figured out (looks better too):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int thisIndex = i;
    <div>@thisIndex</div>;
}

@code {
}
```